# res.send after two forEach have finished executing

Tags: node.js, api-design

```
const collect = [];
req.body.product.forEach(function(entry) {
    mongoClient.connect(databaseServerUrl, function(err, db) {
        let testCollection = db.collection('Tests');
        testCollection.find({Product: entry}).toArray((err, docs) => {
            let waiting = docs.length;
            docs.forEach(function (doc) {
                collect.push(doc);
                finish();
            });
            function finish() {
                waiting--;
                if (waiting === 0) {
                    res.send(collect);
                }
            }
        });
        db.close();
    });
});
```

this is only getting back the first set. If I have two nodes in my array of req.body.product for example. I am only getting back the first set. But I need to get back everything not just from one Collection.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just getting all of the results in a single query, e.g. `.find({ $or: req.body.product.map(entry => ({ Product: entry })) })`?

Comment: Perfect. I like this. If you had answered my question. I would vote this as the answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: I've posted an answer. Please let me know if it works for you, since I wasn't able to actually test it (and I'm not really a MongoDB user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than performing two queries and combining the results into one array, I suggest performing a single query that gets all of the results, which would look something like this:

```
mongoClient.connect(databaseServerUrl, function(err, db) {
    const query = { $or: req.body.product.map(Product => ({ Product })) };
    db.collection('Tests').find(query).toArray((err, docs) => {
        // ...handle `err` here...
        res.send(docs);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Note that I haven't tested this since I don't have a MongoDB database in front of me.

Comment: This works!!! Although I am chaining the find query with a text search statement.

Answer (score -1):

your `mongoClient.connect()` is asyncronous but your loop just execute without waiting for the callback.

Try async forEach loop: [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)

This should solve your problem